# Javascript loads only refresh. Trying to connect html with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am making a project with jquery mobile i am creating an app. Basically its when you click on the menu Calendar icon it should redirect you to javascript calendar event. But calendar shows only after refresh. Im tried everything but cant figure it out. thank you!

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">
  <div data-role="header" class="ui-content">  
    <div class="content" data-role="content">
      <h1 id="new">project</h1>
      <p id="p1"></p`
      <a href="calendar1.php" data-theme="" id="Calendar1"> 
      <img src="img/calendar-new1.png" width="185" height="165">
      <p id="Calendar1"> Calendar </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And Javascript calendar :

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var date1 = new Date();
    var date2 = new Date();
    var date3 = new Date();
    var date4 = new Date();
    var date5 = new Date();
    var date6 = new Date();
    var date7 = new Date();
    var date8 = new Date();
    var date9 = new Date();
}
</script>
```

EDIT :
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xhegn04o/3/)
the code is here

Comment: are you linking to jquery cdn

Comment: You've got `Calender1` as an ID twice and your HTML is a mess. Try fixing that up first.

Comment: Is the included code complete? That javascript won't even do anything since it has mismatched parentheses and braces.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/xhegn04o/ the code is here

Comment: Please, edit your JSFiddle. The one you are currently providing don't include JQuery, there is HTML in the JavaScript textbox, and you even put PHP in it.

Comment: @Seblor hey man , could you explain that more to me? I didnt get much what should i do. thanks man

Comment: In JSFiddle, you just have to put JavaScript in the JavaScript textbox, the HTML in the HTML textbox, and the CSS in the CSS textbox. Do not mix them, or nothing will work. In hte HTML textbox, don't put the `html` or `head` tags. just the `body` tag. If you need JQuery, add it as external library on the left side of the page.

Comment: @Darius, I have updated your code with respective pieces in each code box..see this -->. https://jsfiddle.net/xhegn04o/2/. Next time, please put code (HTML, CSS, Javascript) in respective boxes without additional tags.

Comment: Please show the relevant code directly in the question. The JS that you have shown wouldn't do anything even if it didn't have a syntax error (missing`)` at the end).